# Mobile site not scaling with viewport

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design

I'm  trying a responsive design for a website i'm working on, but every mobile browser will not scale the site properly. Every browser displays the site as a 1000px or more. I've tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
and it has not worked.

Can anyone please help me this is the most frustrating thing

Comment: html, css, link, fiddler would be helpfull

Comment: @reyaner thisisvisual.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must have been a cache issue or something

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#navwrap {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90px;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

not this:

```
#navwrap {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't change the fact that the mobile browser is displaying the website as ~1200x800 with viewport tag

Comment: well now it seems to be working, but i have no clue why all the sudden it's scaling correctly

Comment: must have been a cache issue or something